# When I use android studio ndkBuild to budild the c++, arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

When I use android studio ndkBuild to budild the c++ code, I got error that can't find the static library:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: E:WorkSpaceAndroid_AvatarAvatarmobilesrcmaincpp/prebuild/TTS/ThirdParty/TextAnalysis/armeabi-v7a/lib/libTextAnalysisMain.a: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: E:WorkSpaceAndroid_AvatarAvatarmobilesrcmaincpp/prebuild/TTS/ThirdParty/boost_1_53_0/armeabi-v7a/lib/libboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_53.a: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: E:WorkSpaceAndroid_AvatarAvatarmobilesrcmaincpp/prebuild/TTS/ThirdParty/openfst_1_3_3/armeabi-v7a/lib/libopenfst.a: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: E:WorkSpaceAndroid_AvatarAvatarmobilesrcmaincpp/prebuild/TTS/ThirdParty/Ne10/lib/libNE10.fPIC.a: No such file or directory
```

The slash of the path of the static library disappeared like

```
E:WorkSpaceAndroid_AvatarAvatarmobilesrcmaincpp/
```

This got error 'No such file or directory', the original path is

```
E:\WorkSpace\Android_Avatar\Avatar\mobile\src\main\cpp\/prebuild
```

Did anyone encounter this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to set the path as `E:/WorkSpace/Android_Avatar/Avatar/mobile/src/main/cpp/prebuild` ?

Comment: Can you share your Android.mk?